# Delete Video Cache and apply change in video editing?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I seriously don't really know the right term for it, so sorry for the confusing question... Issue: I use Blender for video editing. I imported my video and realized, I don't like the color. I go to my other software, change it, export it as mp4 and reimport it in Blender. The change does not apply.

I clicked on refresh, still old sequence.
I clicked on my video sequence in the timeline -> source and chose manually the file from my folder, the change still does not apply. Restarting Blender does not help either.
The only working solution is renaming the file, which I would love to avoid. My files are beautiful structured and it would mess everything up.

I assume there's somewhere a stored cash? Or something else? Not in the tmp folder, I already looked. Does anyone know how to apply a changed video, without having to rename it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch off Use Proxies, since they're not re-rendered when you switch source files. If you want the proxies rerendered change the Proxy Render Size:

[image]

Comment: Hm, I tested it over the week-end and it seemed to worked but somehow, this method doesn't work anymore and I'm back to square one.

Comment: There is also the cache, you can switch that off in the sidebar.